# How to pass child with parent's onmouseover event?

Tags: javascript, html, triggers, onmouseover

`onmouseover` triggers whenever mouse enters the element or one of it's children. Is there a nice way of setting `onmouseover` event only on the parent, but so it passes the currently hovered element (which triggered the event) in the argument?

```
 <div id="parent" onmouseover="foo(triggerElement)">  <!-- this ofc doesn't work. How to write this? -->
   <div id="child1" onmouseover="foo(this)">Child 1</div>
   <div id="child2" onmouseover="foo(this)">Child 2</div>
   <div id="child3" onmouseover="foo(this)">Child 3</div>
   <!-- I don't want to set the same onmouseover event for each child -->
 </div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b89573tu/)

I could of course add onmouseover attribute to each individual child of the div with argument 'this' with javascript, but that doesn't seem too nice. Is there a nicer way?

Comment: Maybe `onmouseenter`?

Comment: Try googling event bubbling. You can set in what order events fire :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do that

```
document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event) {
    if (event.target !== this)
        event.target.innerHTML = "You just hovered " + event.target.id;
}, true);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/b89573tu/1/)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks ^^